# Why Logstash reloading duplicate data from file in Linux?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash, elasticsearch and kibana. 
My logstash configuration file is as follows.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/rocky/Logging/logFiles/test1.txt"
    start_position => "end"
    sincedb_path => "test.db"
 }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

When I am running Logstash in windows environment it is working fine, but when I am using same configuration in my virtual Linux OS (Fedora) it is creating a problem. 
In fedora when i am inserting anything at the end of the log file when logstash is running. Sometimes it is sending all data of the file from beginning, sometimes half data. But it should only load new data appended to that log file. also sincedb file is storing data correctly. Still it is nor giving proper data in Fedora. Please help.

Comment: How are you editing the file? Logstash remembers how many bytes of input it has read -- if you do anything other than append to the file, that will effectively corrupt the `sincedb` file.

Comment: I am adding new lines in the log file at the end of the file, and the sincedb file is getting updated correctly, still it is not reading log file correctly. @rutter

Comment: I actually had similar issues, but with windows platform, where a number of issues with file input and sincedb are documented. I found it's wise to always control the document_id, whenever possible, not only because of various issues with logstash, but also because you never know when you'll have to run partial old logs again that didn't digest because of other malfunctions, like elasticsearch, or networking, etc'. Setting the document_id protects your data.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my LinuxMint machine using the official logstash docker image.
I was using a text editor (Geany) to add new lines to the file. After playing around a bit more, I figured out that it must have been related to what my text editor (Geany) was doing when saving the file after I added new lines.

When I added new lines using a simple echo command instead, things worked fine:

```
echo "some new line" >> my_file.log
```

I know this thread is old, but this was the only thing that came up at all when I googled for this, so hopefully this will help someone else...